# stanzajs send simple message to groupchat

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, stanza.io

I am trying to implement simple stanzajs groupchat but in tests its unclear from and to variables.

```js
test('MUC chat', () => {
    const client = createClient({});

    const incoming: ReceivedMessage = {
        body: 'yayyyy',
        from: 'room@rooms.test/member',
        to: 'tester@localhost',
        type: 'groupchat'
    };

    client.on('groupchat', msg => {
        expect(msg).toStrictEqual(incoming);
    });

    client.emit('message', incoming);
});
```

https://github.com/legastero/stanza/blob/master/test/muc/messages.ts
there is no errors, but the other user and room cant see the message. How can I send a public message to room. i dont understand why to: variable is a user rather then room name

```js
this.client.on('groupchat', msg => {
    console.log("groupchat new")
    console.log(msg)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only an account that joined the room (an occupant in the room) can send messages to the room.

You should install a well known Jabber/XMPP client, for example Gajim, Psi, Tkabber... Those clients have a "XML console" that allows you to see what stanzas they send and receive.

Compare what they send with what you are sending, and you will find the probem.